# How to add multiple labels to a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and a list of nodes as follows.

```
     node     title     description
0  "node1"  "nn nn."  "nnnn nnnn"
1  "node2"  "mm mm."  "mmmm mmmm"
2  "node3"  "ll ll."  "llll llll"
3  "node4"  "jj jj."  "jjjj jjjj"

nodes = [["node4", 0.9], ["node2", 1.0], ["node3", 0.8]]
```

I want to add another column to the dataframe as `level` where

- `high` means the value of the node is above `0.8`
- `med` means the value of the node is in between `0.8-0.6`
- `low` means the value of the node is below `0.6`
- `N/A` means the node is not in `nodes` list.

So my output should look as follows.

```
     node     title     description  level
0  "node1"  "nn nn."  "nnnn nnnn"     N/A
1  "node2"  "mm mm."  "mmmm mmmm"     high
2  "node3"  "ll ll."  "llll llll"     med
3  "node4"  "jj jj."  "jjjj jjjj"     high
```

I am currently using the below code to check if the node is in the list or not (which returns a boolean value `0` and `1`).

```
df['node'].isin(nodes).astype(int)
```

However, I am not sure how I can if conditions to divide the data into categories.

I am happy to provide ore details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the values of list and [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for conditional assignment of the values:

```
s=df.node.map(dict(nodes))
df['level']=np.select([s.lt(.6),s.ge(0.6)&s.le(.8),s.gt(0.8)],['low','med','high'],'N/A')
print(df)
```

---

```
    node   title description level
0  node1  nn nn.   nnnn nnnn   N/A
1  node2  mm mm.   mmmm mmmm  high
2  node3  ll ll.   llll llll   med
3  node4  jj jj.   jjjj jjjj  high
```

Note if the strings in the df has `"` , replace them using `df=df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"',''))`

Answer (score 1):

first convert list into dataframe

then apply [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

use `df.loc` and apply conditions

then drop `node_values`

```
nodes = [["node4", 0.9], ["node2", 1.0], ["node3", 0.8]]
node_values = pd.DataFrame(nodes,columns=["node","node_value"])

df = pd.merge(df,node_values,on=['node'],how='left')
df.loc[(df['node_value']<=0.8) & (df['node_value']>=0.6),"level"] = "mid"
df.loc[(df['node_value']>0.8),"level"] = "high"
df.loc[(df['node_value']<0.6),"level"] = "low"

df.drop(['node_value'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
    node   title description level
0  node1  nn nn.   nnnn nnnn   N/A
1  node2  mm mm.   mmmm mmmm  high
2  node3  ll ll.   llll llll   med
3  node4  jj jj.   jjjj jjjj  high
```